# Problem prototype inheritance res partner odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

I create new class by prototype inheritance from res partner and add fields and methods, but this has effect on res partner creation from UI I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception

    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 583, in dispatch

    result = self._call_function(**self.params)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function

    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper

    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call

    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 812, in __call__

    return self.method(*args, **kw)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 412, in response_wrap

    response = f(*args, **kw)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw

    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw

    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper

    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api

    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper

    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 582, in create

    return super(res_partner, self).create(vals)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper

    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api

    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 381, in create

    thread_id = super(mail_thread, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper

    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api

    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4101, in create

    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper

    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api

    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4313, in _create

    cr, user, ids, fields2, context)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper

    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4451, in _store_set_values

    result = column.get(cr, self, ids, f, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1462, in get

    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 223, in <lambda>

    _commercial_partner_id = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: self._commercial_partner_compute(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper

    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 210, in _commercial_partner_compute

    while not current_partner.is_company and current_partner.parent_id:

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 841, in __get__

    return record._cache[self]

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 6057, in __getitem__

    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value

  File "/vagrant/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 56, in get

    raise self.exception

MissingError: ('MissingError', u'One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.')
```

Comment: Do you still get the same error after refreshing?

Comment: yes still get the same Missing Error !

Comment: Please show how you inherit `res.partner` model

Comment: class NewPartner(models.Model):
    _name = "new.partner"
    _description = "new.partner"
    _inherit = ['res.partner', 'mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    _rec_name = "name"

Comment: Anything wrong in this ?

Comment: I can see in the log that the problem in create method but I can't figure the origin of this bug ?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, it worked on Odoo 12

Comment: The error happens when Odoo calls the fields.function's and try to stores the resulting values in the database directly. When Odoo initializes fields and process store parameter it uses the key defined in store dictionary as model name (res.partner) and the class name new.partner as the model name in the trigger list. It happens exactly when it tries to get column value from a new partner using res partner ids, If you look in the res partner class you will see that res.partner model name is hardcoded in some fields when it defines the store attribute.

Comment: I see but what is the solution ? I can't use the prototype inheritance in that case ?

Comment: You can use prototype inheritance but you must update those fields to use the new partner model. I added an example. Check my answer below.

Comment: Did you fix that error?

Comment: yees thank youu for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when Odoo calls the `fields.function's` and try to stores the resulting values in the database directly.

When Odoo initializes fields and process store parameter it uses the key defined in store dictionary as model name (`res.partner`) and the class name `new.partner` as the model name in the trigger list.

It happens exactly when it tries to get column value from a new partner using res partner ids, If you look in the res partner class you will see that `res.partner` model name is hardcoded in some fields when it defines the `store` attribute.

To avoid that issue you can redefine the `commercial_partner_id` field and set the store model to `new.partner`.

***Example: alter `res.partner` fields store model***

```py
class NewPartner(osv.Model):
    _name = "new.partner"
    _description = "new.partner"
    _inherit = ['res.partner', 'mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    _rec_name = "name"

    @api.multi
    def _get_image(self, name, args):
        return dict((p.id, tools.image_get_resized_images(p.image)) for p in self)

    @api.one
    def _set_image(self, name, value, args):
        return self.write({'image': tools.image_resize_image_big(value)})

    _commercial_partner_id = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: self._commercial_partner_compute(*args, **kwargs)
    _display_name = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: self._display_name_compute(*args, **kwargs)

    _commercial_partner_store_triggers = {
        'new.partner': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, context=None: self.search(cr, uid, [('id', 'child_of', ids)], context=dict(active_test=False)),
                        ['parent_id', 'is_company'], 10)
    }
    _display_name_store_triggers = {
        'new.partner': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, context=None: self.search(cr, uid, [('id', 'child_of', ids)], context=dict(active_test=False)),
                        ['parent_id', 'is_company', 'name'], 10)
    }

    _columns = {
        'display_name': fields.function(_display_name, type='char', string='Name', store=_display_name_store_triggers, select=True),
        'parent_id': fields.many2one('new.partner', 'Related Company', select=True),
        'child_ids': fields.one2many('new.partner', 'parent_id', 'Contacts', domain=[('active', '=', True)]),
        'image_medium': fields.function(_get_image, fnct_inv=_set_image,
                                        string="Medium-sized image", type="binary", multi="_get_image",
                                        store={
                                            'new.partner': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['image'], 10),
                                        },
                                        help="Medium-sized image of this contact. It is automatically " \
                                             "resized as a 128x128px image, with aspect ratio preserved. " \
                                             "Use this field in form views or some kanban views."),

        'image_small': fields.function(_get_image, fnct_inv=_set_image,
                                       string="Small-sized image", type="binary", multi="_get_image",
                                       store={
                                           'new.partner': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['image'], 10),
                                       },
                                       help="Small-sized image of this contact. It is automatically " \
                                            "resized as a 64x64px image, with aspect ratio preserved. " \
                                            "Use this field anywhere a small image is required."),

        'commercial_partner_id': fields.function(_commercial_partner_id, type='many2one', relation='new.partner', string='Commercial Entity',
                                                 store=_commercial_partner_store_triggers)
    }
```